# how to migrate the CDN affected magento site

Tags: migration, cdn

we have a magento site with affected by CDN. ex : www.abc.com

we have to migrate the magento site to one more domain. ex : xyz.com

but after moving still the site is affecting from CDN.

means the css js and images are serving from abc.com only.

please help me how we can remove the cdn from the site and how to migrate that site to new domain.

Comment: Did you update the media base URL in configuration to the new CDN?

Comment: ya, we removed cdn.abc.com to xyz.com ,but still the xyz site is accessing cs, media from cdn.abc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,you need clear cache

Check `memecache,redis etc` is exits in system then flush  those.

third,You need `check skin,js url from System>Configuration>Website Base skin,Base js url.`

As magento have multi scope setting that you need to check that setting at
each scope-> `Default Config,Main Website/Main Store,`

Comment: i removed cache under var folder, form where i have to remove memecache,redis etc

Comment: you need to flush redis and memcache and You can check it configuration at local.xml at app/etc/local.xml

Comment: how to check in local.xml , here is our local.xml file = http://pastebin.com/b2Em1gYG what line i have to delete ?

Comment: redis & memcache is not install on your system

Comment: than i have to change only in System>Configuration>Website Base skin,Base js url, am right, okay than i will try there only.....